# API implementation blank return

Tags: php

In the process of implementing an API for my website, however, there is no output when I execute the  code.

```
    function getArticles()
{
      //Error Reporting
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);

        //Get connection variable
        global $conn;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Article";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result=$stmt->get_result();
        $rows = array();
        while($r = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $rows[] = $r;
        }
        return json_encode($rows);
    }
^ Is my api file 'api-article' and it contains the function that displays all the articles.



      <div class="row" id="article">
        <?php
            ini_set("display_errors", 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            include("../model/api-article.php") ;
            $articleTxt = getArticles();
            $articleJson = json_decode($articleTxt);

            //print all articles
            for($i=0;$i<sizeof($articleJson);$i++)
            {
                echo '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" id="articleDiv">';
                    echo "<img class='img-responsive' id='articleImage' src=".$articleJson[$i]->articleThumbnail .">";
                    echo '<h3><a href="article.php?id='.$articleJson[$i] -> articleId.'">'.$articleJson[$i]->articleHeadline .'</a></h3>';
                    echo '<p>',$articleJson[$i]->articleSummary," ",'</p>';
                    echo '<div class="row" id="rowDetails">';
                        echo '<p>' , $articleJson[$i]->articleDate," | " , $articleJson[$i]->articleTopic,'</p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>

    </div> <!--Row end-->
```

Code (index.php) that calls the API and then displays it in a

From my experience the code seems correct symantically, however there are some areas that are causing some confussion. For exmaple, at the minute there is no output from the code. When I change the for loop in  the index.php to be:

```
for($i=0;$i<8;$i++) --EXAMPLE
```

The code runs and displays an error message pointing at line 13 of index.php, displaying:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Is there another way to decode the json when using mysqli OO?

Comment: try changing `$articleJson = json_decode($articleTxt);` to `$articleJson = json_decode($articleTxt, true);`

Comment: No return still, must already be passing as true